# Shuffle items from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to shuffle items from Firebase Database?

Let's say my DB contains 4 items [1,2,3,4]. In my RecyclerView, I want to display shuffled, something like [2,3,1,4]. How can I do that?

This is the code in my Fragment. So it works retrieving data but I need to shuffle it before displaying.

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mRef;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (rootView == null) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store, viewGroup, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);

        mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));

        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Store");
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

For retrieving data from Firebase Database I am using the following code:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Store2> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Store2>()
                    .setQuery(mRef, Store2.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Store2, StoreHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Store2, StoreHolder>(options) {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public StoreHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.store_gridview, parent, false);

                    return new StoreHolder(view);
                }
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final StoreHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Store2 model) {
                    holder.setDetails(getContext(), model.getImage(), model.getName(), model.getPrice());
                }

            };

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}
```

Comment: you need to shuffle your list on your own, check out the following link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-or-randomize-a-list-in-java/

Comment: If you want to do this, you won't be able to use FirestoreRecyclerAdapter as you are now.  You will have to instead manually query the database, populate a List with the items to display, shuffle the list, then feed that list into a regular ListAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DougStevenson and @frankenstein mentioned, I added all items into a list, then I was able the shuffle it using `Collections.shuffle(arrayList);`

I couldn't do it using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, and I needed a custom `Adapter` for my `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.

What is the downside of not using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`? Or is it any? Maybe someone with experience can answer this question.

My fragment:

```
private View rootView;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private StoreAdapter storeAdapter;

private ArrayList<Store> arrayStore;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (rootView == null) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store, viewGroup, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);

        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Data");

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                arrayStore = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Store store = snapshot.getValue(Store.class);
                    arrayStore.add(store);
                }

                storeAdapter = new StoreAdapter(getActivity() ,arrayStore);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(storeAdapter);
                Collections.shuffle(arrayStore, new Random(3));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
    return rootView;
}
```

My adapter:

```
private final Context context;
private ArrayList<Store> arrayStore;

public StoreAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Store> arrayStore) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayStore = arrayStore;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public StoreAdapter.GameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    return new StoreAdapter.GameViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.store_gridview, viewGroup, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final StoreAdapter.GameViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    setColor(viewHolder);

    viewHolder.itemName.setText(arrayStore.get(position).getName());

    Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext())
            .load(arrayStore.get(position).getImage())
            .thumbnail(0.75f)
            .into(viewHolder.itemImage);

    viewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendData(viewHolder, position);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayStore.size();
}

class GameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final View view;

    private final ImageView itemImage, itemRarity;
    private final TextView itemName;

    GameViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.view = itemView;

        itemRarity = view.findViewById(R.id.itemRarity);
        itemImage = view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);

        itemName = view.findViewById(R.id.itemName);

    }
}

private void sendData(@NonNull final StoreAdapter.GameViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    if (viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", arrayStore.get(position).getName());
        intent.putExtra("rarity", arrayStore.get(position).getRarity());
        intent.putExtra("item", arrayStore.get(position).getImage());
        intent.putExtra("price", arrayStore.get(position).getPrice());
        intent.putExtra("key", "Store");
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void setColor(@NonNull final StoreAdapter.GameViewHolder viewHolder) {
    String rarity = arrayStore.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getRarity();

    if (rarity.contains("legendary")) {
        viewHolder.itemRarity.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_legendary_gradient);
    } else if (rarity.contains("classic")) {
        viewHolder.itemRarity.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_classic_gradient);
    } else if (rarity.contains("epic")) {
        viewHolder.itemRarity.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_epic_gradient);
    } else if (rarity.contains("elite")) {
        viewHolder.itemRarity.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_elite_gradient);
    } else if (rarity.contains("rare")) {
        viewHolder.itemRarity.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_rare_gradient);
    } else if (rarity.contains("special")) {
        viewHolder.itemRarity.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_special_gradient);
    }
}
```

My bean class:

```
private String image, name, price, rarity;

public Store() {
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public String getRarity() {
    return rarity;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no option available for `shuffling` data in  `firebase`.
But you can do it locally .

Pass your list in this.

```
Collections.shuffle(arrayList);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the following reference:

```
mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Store");
```

It means that you are trying to display all children that exist under `Store` node. If under this node you store children that are added using the `push()` method, the default ordering is chronological, since every pushed id contains a time component. If you want to change this behaviour, you need to get all the items and shuffle them manually.

As @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, you have to use the same reference, get all items, add them to a list, shuffle them and then use a `ListAdapter` for that.

Please also note, that when you pass a `DocumentReference` or a `Query` object to the `setQuery()` method, where is no further mechanism that can help you shuffle your items. Unfortunately, you'll lose the benefits of the Firebase-UI library but you'll get your work done.